# MYCQL DB - joining-combining two reports (sql requests) on one list

Tags: mysql, join

I need to join two reports together...

First table "Orders" have fields with many records like:

```
id|ContractDate|TotalPrice
-------------------------- 
5 |2015-01-03  |200.30
4 |2015-12-28  |100.70
3 |2014-01-03  |150.30
2 |2014-12-28  |30.70
1 |2013-10-02  |50.20
```

First sql displays:

```
Year|Turnover|Quantity|EurPerOrder
---------------------------------
2015|301.00  |2       |150.50
2014|181.00  |2       |90.50
2013|50.20   |1       |50.20
```

Second table "Projects" have fields with many records like:

```
requestid | Date      |Price 
-------------------------------
5         |2015-01-03 |2000.00
4         |2015-12-28 |1000.00
3         |2014-12-01 |5000.00
2         |2012-12-02 |4000.00
1         |2012-12-28 |6000.00
```

Second sql displays:

```
Year|Turnover|Quantity|EurPerOrder
----------------------------------
2015|3000.00 |2       |1500.00
2014|5000.00 |1       |5000.00
2012|10000.00|2       |50000.00
```

I would like to display both table data on one list like:

```
Year|TurnoverOftable1|QuantityOftable1|EurPerOrderOftable1|TurnoverOftable2|QuantityOftable2|EurPerOrderOftable2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015|301.00          |2               |150.50             |3000.00         |2               |1500.00   
2014|181.00          |2               |90.50              |5000.00         |1               |5000.00   
2013|50.20           |1               |50.20              |*               |*               |*    
2012|*               |*               |*                  |10000.00        |2               |50000.00
```

The **"*"** is 0 or `NULL`

First sql code is:

```
SELECT Year(orders.date) AS Year,
  Sum(orders.price) AS Turnover,
  Count(orders.requestid) AS Quantity,
  ROUND(Sum(orders.price) / Count(orders.requestid), 0) AS EurPerOrder
FROM orders
GROUP BY Year(orders.date) * 100
ORDER BY orders.date DESC
```

Second sql code is:

```
SELECT Year(projects.ContractDate) AS Year,
  Sum(projects.TotalPrice) AS Turnover,
  Count(projects.id) AS Quantity,
  ROUND(Sum(projects.TotalPrice) / Count(projects.id), 0) AS EurPerOrder
FROM projects
GROUP BY Year(projects.ContractDate) * 100
ORDER BY projects.ContractDate DESC
```

My sql groups by year and shows all columns but the calculations are wrong:

```
SELECT 

Year(orders.date) AS Year,
Sum(orders.price) AS TurnoverOftable1,
Count(orders.requestid) AS QuantityOftable1,
ROUND(Sum(orders.price) / Count(orders.requestid), 0) AS EurPerOrderOftable1,

Sum(projects.TotalPrice) AS TurnoverOftable2,
Count(projects.id) AS QuantityOftable2, 
ROUND(Sum(projects.TotalPrice) / Count(projects.id), 0) AS EurPerOrderOftable2    
FROM 
orders
LEFT JOIN    projects  
ON Year(orders.date) = Year(projects.ContractDate)   
GROUP BY 
Year(orders.date) * 100, Year(projects.ContractDate) * 100    
ORDER BY 
orders.date DESC, projects.ContractDate DESC
```

I WOULD VERY APRECIATE IF SOMEBODY HELP ME TO JOIN THOSE TWO REPORTS! Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like following:

```
SELECT q1.Year, q1.Turnover, q1.Quantity, q1.EurPerOrder, q2.Turnover, q2.Quantity, q2.EurPerOrder
FROM (SELECT Year(orders.date) AS Year,
      Sum(orders.price) AS Turnover,
      Count(orders.requestid) AS Quantity,
      ROUND(Sum(orders.price) / Count(orders.requestid), 0) AS EurPerOrder
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY Year(orders.date) * 100
      ORDER BY orders.date DESC ) as q1
LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT Year(projects.ContractDate) AS Year,
       Sum(projects.TotalPrice) AS Turnover,
       Count(projects.id) AS Quantity,
       ROUND(Sum(projects.TotalPrice) / Count(projects.id), 0) AS EurPerOrder
       FROM projects
       GROUP BY Year(projects.ContractDate) * 100
       ORDER BY projects.ContractDate DESC) as q2
ON q1.Year = q2.Year
```

Comment: My dear, would you please help me to join summ result additionally to get result like:

Year|TurnoverOftable1|QuantityOftable1|EurPerOrderOftable1|TurnoverOftable2|QuantityOftable2|EurPerOrderOftable2|TurnoverOftable1+TurnoverOftable2|QuantityOftable1+QuantityOftable2|EurPerOrderOftable1+EurPerOrderOftable2|

Comment: could you please reward Stan with a green check mark which signifies he answered it

Comment: @tester, think this should be something easy as adding 'q1.EurPerOrder+q2.EurPerOrder' to the end of SELECT statement.